# How to make toast message when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm creating a quiz. I have 3 buttons (options) in the activity and its corresponding questions. Now, my problem is I want to show the toast message, when the user chose the correct answer the toast message will appear in a few seconds, but when the user choose the wrong answer it will again display the toast message. I do not know how to do that.

I have done many research and read forums, but seems I don't understand and it don't meet my needs. Can someone please help? thanks in advance!

So far, here is the code. But it doesn't work.
Please correct me which code is wrong. Thanks deeply.

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt1_a);
    btn1.isClickable();
    switch(arg0.getId()){  
      case R.id.btnopt1_a:  
          if(btn1.isPressed()){  
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  
           }  
           else btn1.setText("Your answer is wrong!, The correct answer is: Frog");  
             break;  
           }
      }
    });
```

Comment: The message is shown because you always show the toast on button click and never check the answer in your code.

Answer (score 9):

To show toast message when you click button, use the following code. If you want to do some validations then use the code in your onclicklistener of button:

```
Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt1_a);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, First `implements` Your `Activity  OnClickListener` . And then each end every click check condition you will get solution.

```
public class Deals extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);
        //declare ur buttons here
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.menu: {
                // Do your stuff here
                // call method
                if (isright) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your answer wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many conditions in which you have to show toast. Then it would be better to make a method which shows it.

```
private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And call the above method in the `onClick()` or wherever you want to show.

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v)  {
       ..................
       ..........................

       case R.id.btnopt1_a:  
           if (btn1.isPressed()) {
               showToast("Your answer is correct!");
           } else {
               showToast("Your answer is wrong!, The correct answer is: Frog");
           }

           break;
       });
```